# How do I protect a password stored on server?

Tags: django, python-3.x, smtp, webserver, password-protection

So, I set up a Django project and I'm done with it. Anyway, there's a function in the views.py script that is meant to send an email. I'm using the smtplib library and of course I need to login to send the email through my email address, so in that script my email and my password are written.

I'll publish this project (hosted by Heroku) so I'm worring about the password protection.
What do you think? Is the password protected or do I need to protect it in some way? I don't think it could be possible to access the views.py script but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anything like this, you should avoid putting the password in the code at all. Rather, get it from an environment variable, which you can then set via the command line with `heroku config:set`. See [the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can and should use [.env files](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) for this. On heroku you have the [option](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to add environment variables without .env files.

**EDIT:**

A bit of info about .env files: they are used to load environment variables from a file (the .env file). You usually don't commit them to SVN, but an "example" of what should go into the file, which is usually named .env.example. Depending on what's your setup for running the app there are different ways of supplying those environment variables, but you always access them in the same way in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!